# SP2010 moving document sets via workflow causing errors

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, error, document-set

I have 2 libraries that contain document sets, called proposals and approvals. In the proposals library, users can update the document set properties (a yes/no column called 'Move') to yes which initiates a workflow that submits docsets to a drop off library which gets routed to the 'approvals' library based on content organiser rules and the content organiser processing timer job ran nightly.

The workflow hasnt been changed since it was created ive checked the content orgaiser rules and the timer job and they seem fine. But now when users update the 'move' field to 'yes' for a docset, it isnt moving. Here's the workflow:

```
If CurrentItem:Move equals Yes
```

Submit Document Set using Move to `http://yourcompany/yoursite/_vti_bin/officialfile.asmx` with     `docsetcopied` (Output to Variable:submit file result)

```
Else
```

Stop the workflow and log move does not equal `yes`

I can see that the workflow has completed, but the final event before the workflow completes shows the userID of the person who updated the 'move' field plus an outcome of `FileRejected` or `UnknownError`.

A successfully moved docset only shows workflow history events created by System Account, so does anyone know what might be causing this or what the `FileRejected` or `UnknownError` outcome means?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the workflow account cannot access to the destine library, try to use “Impersonate Step” and add the action into this step, check if the issue exists.

You can check the reference: [SharePoint 2010 - Configuring List Item Permissions with Workflow](http://johnliu.net/blog/2010/7/13/sharepoint-2010-configuring-list-item-permissions-with-workf.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just an update on this one, it appears the errors where due to a number of different reasons based on the document set that was being moved.

- In a few cases the docset was over the 50MB threshhold and errored when moving
- In one case there were empty folders within the docset
- In another case there was an XML file within the docset

Once we adressed these issues the workflow moved the docsets without issue!